# Gradle Binary Plugin: Is it possible to place reusable Kotlin DSL functions in a binary plugin?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would like to put some functions that I've created in several build.gradle.kts files into a more easily shared format than buildSrc.  It seems that one of the benefits espoused about binary plugins is their portability.  Is it possible to create a binary plugin and move these functions into it for reuse by other build.gradle.kts scripts through the plugin mechanism?  I've looked around online and it seems that many people are against using binary plugins to share reusable code.  Is this really considered a bad practice?  If it is possible, it'd be great to see an example somewhere...

Thanks for your time and help,
Mike